# Calculating Time Difference Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to use a query to get a difference in time. Please see the attach screenshot for information. I am trying to find out the difference by sustracting "MapOriginalStart" from "Time". Both of them are formatted to "Short time"[image]

Comment: How about `[MapOriginalStart] - [Time]`? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I tried that too, and I believe because of the AM/PM it is not giving me the right time. Basically, I am just looking for 2.51 on line one and don't care about am/pm. just the difference.

Comment: Then please just recode your time to the correct format. If you don't care about AM or PM, then don't just randomly assign them, but always use AM. Then it will work fine.

Comment: These time are imported from 2 different excel sheets. I am not sure how to convert all of them to AM. Any idea please.

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 1):

Two simple tasks:

**PM to AM conversion:**

```
IIF([MapOriginalStart] > #12:00:00 PM#, [MapOriginalStart] - #12:00:00 PM#, [MapOriginalStart])
IIF([Time] > #12:00:00 PM#, [Time] - #12:00:00 PM#, [Time])
```

**Time substraction:**

(note that `DateDiff`, as referenced by @Christoph, does exist, but you can just as easily use the substraction operator `-`)

```
CDate(Abs([Time] - [MapOriginalStart]))
```

Note that you will probably run into trouble because you're probably not understanding time in Access properly. In Access, 12:51 AM is equal to 00:51 AM. That's a fact, and you will get incorrect results if you expect it to be greater than 10:00 AM

Comment: AM/PM can be done with a little math: `NoAMPM = CDate((SomeTime * 86400 Mod 43200) / 86400)`.

Comment: @Gustav true, my approach will work for this question, and yours will also work when there's actually a date involved. But this will work fine in this instance.

Comment: as you've indicated I am having issues only the start time on or after 10:00 am. so on the first 3 lines, I am getting 09:08:00, 8:45:00 and 08:52:00. everything else shows what is suppose to show. How can I fix this.

Comment: You don't fix that. The first 3 lines do what you designed it to do, you subtract the two times and return the remainder. You can do weird workarounds with things like `If the difference is negative Then add #12:00:00 PM# to it`, but really, the underlying issue is the data and how you import it, you should fix that (for example, you could make Excel calculate the amount of seconds since 00:00 AM, and use that, since that's a valid time parameter you can do calculus with, and doesn't have random AM/PM appended to it).

Comment: Below code brings up the value I wanted.                                                                                                        IIf([Difference]>#12:00:00 AM#,#11:59:59 PM#-([Difference]+#12:00:00 PM#),[Difference])

Comment: That's what I said with the weird workaround part, i just noted that that's not something you should do, because you're now working around errors in your data, while you should fix them. Leaving them and working around them will probably cause problems in the future, unless you're working on a small project

Comment: AM/PM can be done in at least two alternative ways: `NoAMPM = CDate(Format(SomeTime, "h:nn:ss ampm"))` or `NoAMPM = TimeSerial(Hour(SomeTime) Mod 12, Minute(SomeTime), Second(SomeTime))`.

Answer (score 0):

Erik is right. What you are looking for is:

```
TimeDiff: [MapOriginalStart] - [Time]
```

The result is a date value. Format that as `h:nn` to have it displayed as hours and minutes:

```
TimeDiffText: Format([MapOriginalStart] - [Time], "h\.nn")
```

For a *decimal hour* count, you can use:

```
Hours: DateDiff("s", [MapOriginalStart], [Time]) / 3600
```